# NSIS EnvVarUpdate visible in System Properties, but not working

Tags: nsis

I am installing 7-ZIP using NSIS and then looking in the registry to see where it has been installed.  Having detected the install location I am taking the path and creating a system variable named 7-ZIP using the NSIS command below.

```
 ${EnvVarUpdate} $0 "7-ZIP" "A" "HKLM" "<Install Path>"
```

I then append the 7-ZIP var to the PATH var.

After the install has finished I can see the new System var in the System Variables list.

[image]

The new 7-ZIP variable has also been amended to the PATH variable as the image below shows.

[image]

Now the issue I have is that when I start a cmd window and type 7z I would expext it to run the 7z.exe located in the C:\Program Files\7-Zip directory, but it does not and complains it cannot find it.  If I then close the CMD window and edit the 7-ZIP variable, but don't actually chang anything.  The same command then works when i try again with a new CMD window.

I just wonder whether anyone else has experienced this issue and if they found a work around?

Comment: How are you updating %Path%?

Comment: ${EnvVarUpdate} $0 "PATH" "A" "HKLM" "%${varName}%${pathSuffix}"

It's as if the value although visible in the 'System Properties' view has not actually become visible to the OS?

Since posting I read about this

SendMessage ${HWND_BROADCAST} ${WM_WININICHANGE} 0 "STR:Environment" /TIMEOUT=5000

Just wondering whether that always needs to be done when working with System Properties?